# Form not passing along iframe input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have recently been working on a web app that has a form. However, I've run into a roadblock. In this form, there is an `iframe` that has a photo upload. When submitted, the photo is uploaded and lets the user know. There is also a hidden input in a form on this page. In this hidden input, the URL of the image is stored. This is my script that is *supposed* to intercept the value of this input and pass it along in the form:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("photoFrame").contentDocument.forms[0].onsubmit = function () {
        document.getElementById("entry_862192515").setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("photoFrame").contentDocument.forms[0].getElementById("photoUrl").value);
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" name="select_frame" src="/photo-upload.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" id="photoFrame"></iframe>
```

`photo-upload.php` is just a simple form that uploads the image. Now here is `upload.php`, the PHP script that uploads the image from a POST request:

```
<?php

// Cloudinary init
require 'Cloudinary.php';
require 'Uploader.php';
require 'Api.php';
\Cloudinary::config(array( 
  "cloud_name" => "(my name)", 
  "api_key" => "(my key)", 
  "api_secret" => "(my secret)"
));

// Uploads images to Cloudinary
$uploaded_file = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

// Declares URL to variable
$url = $uploaded_file['secure_url'];

echo '<form><input type="hidden" id="photoUrl" value="'.$url.'" /></form>';
echo '<b style="color:green;">Success! Photo uploaded. Once you finish filling out the form, click the "Send" button.</b>';

?>
```

What is wrong with this script? I don't see any errors in my console when I run it, and inside the `iframe`, the input contains the URL value. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing your html

Comment: Done! I have now posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form>
  Hidden parent's input for photo URL:
  <input id="saveURL" />
  <iframe name="select_frame" src="iFrame.html" id="photoFrame"></iframe>
</form>

<script>

  // wait till parent loads so we don't trigger it during iFrame's first load
  window.onload = function() {

    var parentFormInput = document.getElementById('saveURL');
    var photoFrame = document.getElementById("photoFrame");

    // executes after the iFrame postback completes
    photoFrame.onload = function() {
      var innerDoc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
      var url = innerDoc.getElementById('photoUrl').value; // iframe input
      parentFormInput.value = url; // saves value to the iframe's parent
    }
  }

</script>
```

iFrame.html contains the form:

```
<form>
  <input id="photoUrl" style="width:60%" readonly="readonly" value="http://somedomain.com/somefile.jpg" />
</form>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/auqk8tQrCYYEIFjJUmPC?p=preview

Comment: If a photo is mandatory you can validate that `saveURL` input field is not empty in the main form's submitting event

Comment: `var parentFormInput = document.getElementById('entry_862192515');
        var photoFrame = document.getElementById("photoFrame");

        photoFrame.contentWindow.onhashchange = function() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var innerDoc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
                var url = innerDoc.getElementById('photoUrl').value; // iframe input
                parentFormInput.value = url; // saves value to the iframe's parent
            }, 500);
        }`

Comment: For some reason, I am still getting this error: `global code — report:53TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'photoFrame.contentWindow')`

Comment: Also, might there be an `iframe`-less way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand why you've added `photoFrame.contentWindow.onhashchange()` and `setTimeout`? I provided you with working code that detects when the iframe refreshes. Also, the likely cause of that error is the browser not supportting `contentWindow`.  That's the reason for having the `this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document` line - to support different browsers

Answer (score 0):

The photo-upload.php file expects a file data to be posted so that is can be retrieved from $_FILES. But when the iframe gets loaded, how come the file data will be posted? I guess it will throw error in php.

Comment: Do you have any other method ideas?

Comment: I can not help you without exactly knowing what you are trying to achieve here. Like why you want to use an iframe in this case, is photo upload going to be initiated by user etc.